# /showIncludes missing some includes

Tags: c++, compiler-flags

I'm using the VS2008 compile flag /showIncludes to analyse a build. But I've hit something that I'm a little unclear about.

I have a file A.h. It includes the following

- windows.h
- memory
- assert.h
- vector

But when I analysis the build log after setting /showIncludes I'm not seeing A.h bring in any of these files.

The only reasons I can think of that would cause this is

1. The VS2008 compiler is smart enough to figure out that these files are not required (which seems unlikely)
2. The pre-compiled header (which contains these files) includes them on behalf of A.h and hence they are not listed by /showIncludes

Are either of these guesses correct? Is there any other explanation?

Comment: Yeah, `#pragma once` may be doing this. I'd say that's a confusing implementation, but it certainly wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: That does sound reasonable. At least for the current compilation unit.

Comment: Want to officially answer this?

Comment: I have nothing beyond this guess, I'm afraid!